# Delete all script code when saving an HTML file

Tags: notepad++, regex

I save and archive a lot of Paypal receipts, and the files come with tons of garbage script code not necessary for archival purposes.  I would like to come up with a way to strip all that code so I can delete the included javascript files to save space without breaking the look of the receipt.

Tried the 'find and replace' function in Notepad++ with the following regular expression (didn't put anything in the 'replace' field)

```
<script.*?/script>
```

This seems to take care of the issue mostly, but leaves a blank line for all deleted code.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not just print it as a PDF?  Chrome can do it by default or you could download a free pdf printer.

Comment: I thought exactly what @Spencer5051 said... Why reinvent the wheel over a format issue when you can print it digitally and preserve the format (even as your archive retrieval tools and display change over the years?)

Comment: Saving as PDF definitely is the best option. But to solve your regex problem, you can of course include a newline into your search parameter, and replace that final char too. Then the replace will not just remove the script part, but also the line-ending afterwards.

Comment: PDF is not optimal because of file size (we're talking about lots of files on a daily basis).  HTML is also better in case you need to convert the file to another format later, because all the original images are kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(\r\n)*<script.*?/script>(\r\n)*` to remove the script tags along with its leading and trailing blank lines.

Comment: I don't think that can be applied to a whole batch of files, so I'm interested in finding a solution that will not create bank place in the first place.

Comment: @KnocksX sorry I misunderstood that part. I am changing my answer see if it helps or not.

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: This does not work - it only captures tags which are contained on a single line, and does not capture leading whitespace to address the blank lines OP mentioned. A better solution is `(\s)*<script[\s\S]*?\/script>(\s)*`

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it and the accepted answer only captures `<script>` tags which are contained on a single line, and does not capture leading whitespace to address the blank lines. Using `\s` will capture all whitespace characters, including the newlines between the tags in multi-line script blocks. Like so:

`(\s)*<script[\s\S]*?\/script>(\s)*`